# Android GLES20 works on bionic 4.1.2 but not on Samsung 4.4.2

Tags: android, opengl-es, samsung-mobile

I have an app that I'm working on that uses openGL ES 2.0 on an android device. The app contains some buttons that are displayed using programmatic layout controls. This button pad is superimposed on a OpenGl Surface View. When I run the app on the tablet the buttons appear but the Surface View is grey, the color of the background for the 3d model I've created. This leads me to believe there's something wrong with my shaders. I use many uniform vec2's in my fragment shader. I'm looking at this web site:

http://www.shaderific.com/glsl-variables/

and it says there's a built in function that you can use to tell how many uniform vectors your implementations of GL uses. How do I run this code in android?

```
gl_MaxFragmentUniformVectors
```

I print out the contents of GLES20.GL_MAX_FRAGMENT_UNIFORM_VECTORS and I get the number 36349. My shader uses about 20.

If that doesn't lead to anything, this is the basic error. The app works on a Motorola Bionic, Android 4.1.2, but doesn't work on a Samsung Galaxy Tab/Pro, Android 4.4.2! Of course I would like it to work on both.

```
W/ApplicationPackageManager﹕ getCSCPackageItemText()
E/MoreInfoHPW_ViewGroup﹕ Parent view is not a TextView
```

below is a log for the Samsung device.

```
10-10 14:27:03.723  30456-30462/org.android.airplane D/dalvikvm﹕ Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
10-10 14:38:55.833    1269-1269/org.android.airplane I/SELinux﹕ Function: selinux_android_load_priority [0], There is no sepolicy file.
10-10 14:38:55.833    1269-1269/org.android.airplane I/SELinux﹕ Function: selinux_android_load_priority , loading version is VE=SEPF_SM-T320_4.4.2_0018
10-10 14:38:55.833    1269-1269/org.android.airplane I/SELinux﹕ selinux_android_seapp_context_reload: seapp_contexts file is loaded from /seapp_contexts
10-10 14:38:55.843    1269-1269/org.android.airplane D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
10-10 14:38:55.943    1269-1269/org.android.airplane W/ApplicationPackageManager﹕ getCSCPackageItemText()
10-10 14:38:55.983    1269-1269/org.android.airplane E/MoreInfoHPW_ViewGroup﹕ Parent view is not a TextView
10-10 14:38:56.083    1269-1269/org.android.airplane I/Adreno-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  ()
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.24.00.07
    Build Date: 01/22/14 Wed
    Local Branch: base_au149_adreno_au169_patches
    Remote Branch:
    Local Patches:
    Reconstruct Branch:
10-10 14:38:56.113    1269-1269/org.android.airplane D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
10-10 14:38:58.823    1269-1269/org.android.airplane W/ApplicationPackageManager﹕ getCSCPackageItemText()
```

Comment: I have to mention that the GLSurfaceViewRenderer that's supposed to be visible under the buttons shows for a second before it disappears to gray. I did not notice before. It looks, for that brief moment to be complete. In other words, the GL components may actually be working, but I cannot tell for sure.

Comment: I've posted a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26455589/works-on-bionic-4-1-2-but-not-on-samsung-4-4-2  Please take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An update solved the problem. My Samsung device works now!

Answer (score 0):

`GL_MAX_FRAGMENT_UNIFORM_VECTORS` is not the number of uniforms supported. It's an enum value that allows you to query that value. You get the actual value by calling:

```
int valA[] = new int[1];
GLES20.glGetIntegerv(GLES20.GL_MAX_FRAGMENT_UNIFORM_VECTORS, valA, 0);
int maxUniforms = valA[0];
```

The ES 2.0 spec requires implementations to support at least 16 uniform vectors. So it's theoretically possible that you're above the limit if you use 20. I would be surprised if the limit is really that low on a modern device, but you should definitely check.

As with any other kind of OpenGL problems, I'm sure that you already called `glGetError()`, and checked the result.

Other than that, make sure that you check the result of shader compilations and linking with `glGetShaderiv()`, `glGetShaderInfoLog()`, `glGetProgramiv()`, and `glGetProgramInfoLog()`. Some GLSL compilers are stricter than others at enforcing standard compliance, so it's quite common that your shaders will work on some devices even though they contain errors.

Another thing you can try is to call `glValidateProgram()`, and then check the result using `glGetProgramiv()` with the `GL_VALIDATE_STATUS` argument. This is best done after you set up all your state, immediately before making the first draw call. This can report problems with the program that could not be detected at compile/link time because they depend on the settings of other state.

Comment: funny thing is I'm getting 'GLES20.GL_NO_ERROR' from glGetError(). What to do? What is my option if the problem isn't GL?!! I may end up asking another question. This answer is great BUT doesn't solve my problem! The number of uniforms is 224 on the Samsung device. Knowing that is helpful.